# Prepared statement call fails (syntax error and function does not exist) on pl/pgsql block

Tags: postgresql, prepared-statement, plpgsql

The original, PL/pgSQL anonymous block, code to execute is the following:

```
do $$
declare
    tt integer[];
    minRowNum integer;
    maxRowNum integer;
    MIN_TEMS constant integer := 1;
    MAX_TEMS constant integer := 15;
    LAST_ARR_IDX constant integer := MAX_TEMS * 2;
    NUM_FILAS constant integer := 1000;
begin
    create temp table NTematica(rownum, tematica_id) as
    select
        S.n, (S.n * 841)::integer
    from
        generate_series(1,357) S(n);
    select
        min(X.rownum), max(X.rownum) into minRowNum, maxRowNum
    from
        NTematica X;
    prepare selectTematicasPlan(integer, integer, integer, integer) as
        select
            array_agg(X.tematica_id)
        from
            NTematica X
        where
            X.rownum in
            (
            select
                trunc(random() * ($2 - $1 + 1) + $1) :: integer
            from
                generate_series($3, trunc(random() * ($4 - $3 + 1) + $3) :: integer)
            );  
        for i in 1..NUM_FILAS loop
            execute selectTematicasPlan(minRowNum, maxRowNum, MIN_TEMS, MAX_TEMS);          
            raise notice 'First is % and % are the others', tt[1], tt[2:LAST_ARR_IDX];
    end loop;
    drop table NTematica cascade;
    deallocate selectTematicasPlan;
end$$;
```

Then, execution fails with error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 34:       tt := execute selectTematicasPlan(minRowNum, maxRowNum...
```

Then, for testing, I eliminate the "tt :=" and run it again with this result:

```
ERROR:  function selecttematicasplan(integer, integer, integer, integer) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT selectTematicasPlan(minRowNum, maxRowNum, MIN_TEMS, M...
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to   add explicit type casts.
```

**Update:**

Thanks in advance to everyone. I'm going to clarify some questions:

My initial code was an "insert from select" (CTE included) to populate a table with 10 million of records. I can confirm that it was VERY SLOW. So, I decided to choose a IMPERATIVE solution: create an indexed unlogged table (working like a map data structure) and loop 10 million of times to "execute" a data "select" from the "map" followed of a "insert" data. I pull out "select" and "insert" of loop into prepared statements because that avoid 10 million of parsing work to PG. The posted code is only to concerning to my problems with the prepared statements.
Is possible or not to use "prepare"+"execute" in a pl/pgsql code block? PG doc (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-prepare.html, http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-execute.html) does not talk (against or in favor) about pl/pgsql.

NOTE: My database version ("select version()") is:
    PostgreSQL 9.4.4 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 4.9.2-10ubuntu13) 4.9.2, 64-bit

Answer (score 1):

In a PL/pgSQL function you do not use prepared statements. In effect, every statement in a function is "prepared", just like a statement with a `PREPARE` command. In an anonymous code block (which is PL/pgSQL) that looks a tad odd, because the block is used only once then discarded, but in effect it works just the same. [The principle is documented here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-implementation.html#PLPGSQL-PLAN-CACHING) and reference is made to the `PREPARE` statement, which is logical *because the behaviour is essentially the same*: the statements in the code block are parsed and cached for future use. Perhaps somewhat superfluous, but considering the uninformed statements in the various answers to this question I would like to highlight a sentence from the documentation linked to above:

> As each expression and SQL command is first executed in the function, the PL/pgSQL interpreter parses and analyzes the command to create a prepared statement

In short: explicitly creating a prepared statement in a plpgsql code block and then dynamically executing that prepared statement is useless and inefficient and conceptually flawed.

What you are trying to do is to prepare a statement and that preparation is then prepared by the backend and then later you dynamically execute the statement that executes the prepared statement. There is no irony here: this is what happens. Note also that the PL/pgSQL `EXECUTE` statement has no caching whatsoever: the SQL statement `EXECUTE selectTematicasPlan(minRowNum, maxRowNum, MIN_TEMS, MAX_TEMS)` is parsed each and every time it is invoked. It is a fairly simple statement, but (as in [Klin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32944281/3304426)) the parameter values have to passed in every time, even while they are the same on each call. I hope you can see the inefficiency of this approach (if not, I rest my case).

Coming back to your example, your function should be somewhat like this:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
  tt integer[];
  minRowNum integer := 1;
  maxRowNum integer := 357;
  MIN_TEMS constant integer := 1;
  MAX_TEMS constant integer := 15;
  NUM_FILAS constant integer := 1000;
BEGIN
  CREATE TEMP TABLE NTematica(rownum, tematica_id) AS
    SELECT S.n, (S.n * 841)::integer
    FROM generate_series(minRowNum, maxRowNum) S(n);

  -- generate_series() produces numbers from the first parameter to the last, inclusive
  -- no need to query for those values
        select
            min(X.rownum), max(X.rownum) into minRowNum, maxRowNum
        from
            NTematica X;

  FOR i IN 1..NUM_FILAS LOOP
    SELECT array_agg(X.tematica_id) INTO tt
    FROM NTematica X
    WHERE X.rownum IN (
      SELECT trunc(random() * (maxRowNum - minRowNum + 1) + minRowNum)::integer
      FROM generate_series(MIN_TEMS, trunc(random() * (MAX_TEMS - MIN_TEMS + 1) + MIN_TEMS)::integer)
    );  
    RAISE NOTICE 'First is % and % are the others', tt[1], tt[2:array_upper(tt)];
  END LOOP;
  DROP TABLE NTematica;
END; $$;
```

You can also write the anonymous code block as a single SQL statement, here with CTE's for improved readability:

```
WITH params(minRowNum integer, maxRowNum integer, MIN_TEMS integer, MAX_TEMS integer) AS
  SELECT 1, 357, 1, 15
), rowNums(rwNum integer, tematica_id integer) AS (
  SELECT S.n, (S.n * 841)::integer
  FROM params, generate_series(params.minRowNum, params.maxRowNum) S(n)
)
SELECT tt[1] AS first, tt[2:array_upper(tt)] AS rest
FROM generate_series(1, 1000) ON true
JOIN (
  SELECT array_agg(rw.tematica_id) AS tt
  FROM params p, rowNums rw
  WHERE rw.rwNum IN (
    SELECT trunc(random() * (p.maxRowNum - p.minRowNum + 1) + p.minRowNum)::integer
    FROM generate_series(p.MIN_TEMS, trunc(random() * (p.MAX_TEMS - p.MIN_TEMS + 1) + p.MIN_TEMS)::integer)
  ) agg ON true;
```

The parameters that are used multiple times are all in the top line so easy to modify and no risk of inconsistencies. This should be much faster than the anonymous code block because you lose a lot of overhead, not least on the `TEMP TABLE`. Obviously you will get the results as regular tabular data, not as 1,000 notices.

Answer (score 0):

It should not work, you cannot to use SQL commands for prepared statements in PL/pgSQL. It is nonsense - every embedded SQL statements used in PLpgSQL is prepared statement by default.

Comment: Please, tell me the URL of Postgres documentation that says that "prepare" and "execute" cannot be used inside pL/pgSQL block.

Comment: Probably it is not documented - it just not work due fact so plpgsql has statement EXECUTE - that is different than SQL statement EXECUTE. So without ugly workaround you cannot do it.

Comment: @RogerDielrton: See documentation here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-implementation.html#PLPGSQL-PLAN-CACHING